# Adding base url to vector components

Tags: r

im trying to extract some info from tesla forum but the threads come up without the base url https://forums.tesla.com.
Can you please advise on how to append this?
thanks

```
url <- "https://forums.tesla.com/forum/tesla-model-3"

h <- read_html(url)

threads <- h %>%
  html_nodes("#content-body .odd a") %>% html_text()

thread_links <- h %>%
  html_nodes("#content-body .odd a") %>% html_attr(name = "href")

thread_links
 [1] "/forum/forums/please-read-first-posting-forums"                                                       
 [2] "/forum/forums/battery-died-while-vacation"                                                            
 [3] "/forum/forums/tesla-and-motionsickness"                                                               
 [4] "/forum/forums/having-remove-phone-pocket"
```

Comment: `paste0("https://forums.tesla.com", thread_links)`?

Comment: or `thread_links <- h %>% ... %>% paste0("https://forums.tesla.com", .)`

Comment: thanks! the pipe function did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

This is string concatenation, so use `paste0` (or `paste(..., sep="")`:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

threads <- h %>%
  html_nodes("#content-body .odd a") %>% html_text()

thread_links <- h %>%
  html_nodes("#content-body .odd a") %>% 
  html_attr(name = "href") %>%
  paste("https://forums.tesla.com", .)
```

Comment: Andres Mora, does this answer your question? If so, please accept it. Thanks!